# Let $G=(V,E)$ be a planar, connected graph that contains circles. Prove that $|E|= \frac{s}{s-2}(|V|-2)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a planar, connected graph that contains circles, In addition, The shortest circle in the graph has $s$ amount of vertexes.

Prove that $|E|= \frac{s}{s-2}(|V|-2)$

What i did so far was:

1. The shortest circle in the graph will represent the minimum amount of edges of each face, Means $s f\le2|E| \to f\le\frac{2|E|}{s}$
2. Using Euler formula: $|V|+f-|E|=2 \to 2=|V|+f-|E|$ using (1) we'll get $2=|V|+f-|E|\le|V|+\frac{2|E|}{s}-|E|\to 2s=s|V|+2|E|-s|E|\to|E|(s-2)=s(|V|-2)\to|E|\le\frac{s}{s-2}(|V|-2)$

Is that proof enough?

Comment: Please clarify, what is a circle?  Do you mean cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally call the length of the smallest cycle in a graph the **girth**.

So if the girth of $G$ is $g(G) = s$, we want to prove that $$\Vert G \Vert \le \frac{s}{s-2} ( |G| - 2 )$$

Note that equality cannot hold, since $K_4$ and $K_4 - e$ have the same number of vertices and same girth (being composed of triangles), but $K_4 - e$ has one fewer edge.

The proof you give above is correct.  However, to justify the fact that $s \cdot f \le 2 |E|$, you should note that every edge can be on at most $2$ faces.